# Trouble with Next js + Express deployment using Zeit Now

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js, vercel

I have written a simple SSR Next js web page with an express server attached to handle some email functionality I have attached to a contact form.

I have tried deploying to now and, whilst the terminal says I have done so successfully, I get a 502 error when I make network requests to my express server.

now.json:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {"src": "package.json", "use": "@now/next"},
    {"src": "/server/index.js", "use": "@now/node-server"}
  ],
  "routes": [{"src": "/api/contact", "dest": "/server/index.js"}]
}
```

next.config.js:

```
const { PHASE_PRODUCTION_SERVER } =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
    ? {} // We're never in "production server" phase when in development mode
    : !process.env.NOW_REGION 
      ? require('next/constants') // Get values from `next` package when building locally
      : require('next-server/constants'); // Get values from `next-server` package when building on now v2

module.exports = (phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
  if (phase === PHASE_PRODUCTION_SERVER) {
    // Config used to run in production.
    return {};
  }

  const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');

  return withSass();
};
```

I had a look at now-examples but unfortunately this particular combination of libraries isn't represented and I'm not skilled enough a programmer to understand the inner workings of them myself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. My server code is

INDEX.JS

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const mailer = require('./mailer/mailer.js');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  server.use(bodyParser.json());

  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  server.post('/api/contact', (req, res) => {
    const { firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, emailAddress, messageText } = req.body

    mailer.send( firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, emailAddress, messageText ).then(() => {
      console.log(`Sent the message "${messageText}" from <${firstName}> ${emailAddress}.`);
      res.status(200);
      res.send('success')
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(`Failed to send the message "${messageText}" from <${firstName}> ${emailAddress} with the error ${error && error.message}`);
      res.status(400);
      res.send('failure')
    })
  });

  server.listen( (process.env.PORT || 3000) , (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('> Read on http://localhost:3000')
  });

});
```

The rest of my next.js app is very straightforward.

Logs:

```
2019-03-19T11:01:49.575Z  [11:01:49] Compiling client
2019-03-19T11:01:49.598Z  [11:01:49] Compiling server
2019-03-19T11:01:52.602Z  [11:01:52] Compiled server in 3s
2019-03-19T11:02:00.177Z  info fsevents@1.2.7: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
2019-03-19T11:02:00.177Z  info "fsevents@1.2.7" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
2019-03-19T11:02:00.183Z  [3/4] Linking dependencies...
2019-03-19T11:02:00.199Z  warning "@zeit/next-sass > sass-loader@6.0.6" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || >= 3.0.0-rc.0 || ^3.0.0".
2019-03-19T11:02:00.200Z  warning "@zeit/next-sass > @zeit/next-css > css-loader@1.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
                          warning "@zeit/next-sass > @zeit/next-css > mini-css-extract-plugin@0.4.3" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.4.0".
2019-03-19T11:02:00.208Z  warning "next-optimized-images > raw-loader@1.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.3.0".
2019-03-19T11:02:00.209Z  warning "next-optimized-images > file-loader@3.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
                          warning "next-optimized-images > url-loader@1.1.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
2019-03-19T11:02:00.209Z  warning " > react-loading@2.0.3" has unmet peer dependency "prop-types@^15.6.0".
2019-03-19T11:02:02.880Z  [11:02:02] Compiled client in 13s
2019-03-19T11:02:03.396Z  compiling entrypoint with ncc...
2019-03-19T11:02:06.428Z  [4/4] Building fresh packages...
2019-03-19T11:02:08.530Z  success Saved lockfile.
2019-03-19T11:02:08.538Z  Done in 28.73s.
2019-03-19T11:02:08.806Z  yarn cache v1.13.0
2019-03-19T11:02:11.332Z  success Cleared cache.
2019-03-19T11:02:11.332Z  Done in 2.54s.
2019-03-19T11:02:11.341Z  running user script...
2019-03-19T11:02:11.342Z  running "yarn run now-build"
2019-03-19T11:02:11.592Z  yarn run v1.13.0
2019-03-19T11:02:11.670Z  $ NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=3000 next build --lambdas
2019-03-19T11:02:13.254Z  [11:02:13] Compiling client
2019-03-19T11:02:15.907Z  ncc: Module directory "/tmp/6b60c2d/user/node_modules/chokidar/lib" attempted to require "fsevents" but could not be resolved, assuming external.
2019-03-19T11:02:31.586Z  downloading user files...
2019-03-19T11:02:31.679Z  installing dependencies for user's code...
2019-03-19T11:02:31.680Z  installing to /tmp/84eaca5/user/server
2019-03-19T11:02:35.826Z  Browser assets sizes after gzip:

                             19.3 kB  .next/static/0rX3****/pages/_app.js
                             12.3 kB  .next/static/0rX3****/pages/_error.js
                             1.04 kB  .next/static/0rX3****/pages/components/about/About.js
                             6.64 kB  .next/static/0rX3****/pages/components/backtotopbutton/BackToTopButton.js
                             1.14 kB  .next/static/0rX3****/pages/components/bookingcard/BookingCard.js
                               323 B  .next/static/0rX3****/pages/components/bookingcard/components/calendlywidget/CalendlyWidget.js
                             8.31 kB  .next/static/0rX3****/pages/components/contactcard/ContactCard.js
                             8.26 kB  .next/static/0rX3****/pages/components/contactcard/components/contactform/ContactForm.js
                             6.55 kB  .next/static/0rX3****/pages/components/landingcard/LandingCard.js
                             7.09 kB  .next/static/0rX3****/pages/components/mapview/MapContainer.js
                             6.81 kB  .next/static/0rX3****/pages/components/mapview/components/mapview/MapView.js
                             8.49 kB  .next/static/0rX3****/pages/components/navbar/NavBar.js
                             7.91 kB  .next/static/0rX3****/pages/components/navbar/components/burgermenu/BurgerMenu.js
                               478 B  .next/static/0rX3****/pages/components/servicescard/ServicesCard.js
                             25.7 kB  .next/static/0rX3****/pages/index.js
                             56.2 kB  .next/static/chunks/commons.ebad****.js
                               154 B  .next/static/chunks/styles.49ee****.js
                             3.01 kB  .next/static/css/styles.ee9ce638.chunk.css
                             23.4 kB  .next/static/runtime/main-44b4****.js
                               737 B  .next/static/runtime/webpack-8917****.js

2019-03-19T11:02:35.830Z  [11:02:35] Compiled client in 23s
2019-03-19T11:02:35.854Z  [11:02:35] Compiling server
2019-03-19T11:02:36.469Z  npm WARN
2019-03-19T11:02:36.470Z   clevetoothdenture@1.0.0 No repository field.
2019-03-19T11:02:36.470Z  npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/fsevents):
                          npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
2019-03-19T11:02:36.470Z
2019-03-19T11:02:36.470Z  up to date in 4.427s
2019-03-19T11:02:36.657Z  npm
2019-03-19T11:02:36.658Z
2019-03-19T11:02:36.658Z  WARN using --force
2019-03-19T11:02:36.658Z   I sure hope you know what you are doing.
2019-03-19T11:02:36.773Z  writing ncc package.json...
2019-03-19T11:02:36.773Z  installing dependencies for ncc...
2019-03-19T11:02:36.773Z  installing to /tmp/84eaca5/ncc
2019-03-19T11:02:36.938Z  yarn install v1.13.0
2019-03-19T11:02:36.962Z  [1/4] Resolving packages...
2019-03-19T11:02:36.983Z  success Already up-to-date.
2019-03-19T11:02:36.985Z  Done in 0.05s.
2019-03-19T11:02:37.152Z  yarn cache v1.13.0
2019-03-19T11:02:37.173Z  success Cleared cache.
2019-03-19T11:02:37.173Z  Done in 0.03s.
2019-03-19T11:02:55.631Z  [11:02:55] Compiled server in 20s
2019-03-19T11:02:55.737Z  Done in 44.15s.
2019-03-19T11:02:55.743Z  running npm install --production...
2019-03-19T11:02:55.743Z  installing to /tmp/77afa5cd
2019-03-19T11:02:55.994Z  yarn install v1.13.0
2019-03-19T11:02:56.142Z  [1/4] Resolving packages...
2019-03-19T11:02:57.021Z  [2/4] Fetching packages...
2019-03-19T11:03:10.921Z  info fsevents@1.2.7: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
2019-03-19T11:03:10.921Z  info "fsevents@1.2.7" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
2019-03-19T11:03:10.931Z  [3/4] Linking dependencies...
2019-03-19T11:03:10.939Z  warning "@zeit/next-sass > sass-loader@6.0.6" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || >= 3.0.0-rc.0 || ^3.0.0".
2019-03-19T11:03:10.940Z  warning "@zeit/next-sass > @zeit/next-css > css-loader@1.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
                          warning "@zeit/next-sass > @zeit/next-css > mini-css-extract-plugin@0.4.3" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.4.0".
2019-03-19T11:03:10.949Z  warning "next-optimized-images > file-loader@3.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
2019-03-19T11:03:10.950Z  warning "next-optimized-images > raw-loader@1.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.3.0".
2019-03-19T11:03:10.950Z  warning "next-optimized-images > url-loader@1.1.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
2019-03-19T11:03:10.950Z  warning " > react-loading@2.0.3" has unmet peer dependency "prop-types@^15.6.0".
2019-03-19T11:03:13.518Z  [4/4] Building fresh packages...
2019-03-19T11:03:13.567Z  Done in 17.58s.
2019-03-19T11:03:13.834Z  yarn cache v1.13.0
2019-03-19T11:03:16.398Z  success Cleared cache.
2019-03-19T11:03:16.399Z  Done in 2.57s.
2019-03-19T11:03:16.666Z  preparing lambda files...
2019-03-19T11:03:16.840Z  Creating lambda for page: "components/about/About.js"...
2019-03-19T11:03:16.841Z  Creating lambda for page: "components/backtotopbutton/BackToTopButton.js"...
2019-03-19T11:03:16.841Z  Creating lambda for page: "components/bookingcard/BookingCard.js"...
2019-03-19T11:03:16.842Z  Creating lambda for page: "components/bookingcard/components/calendlywidget/CalendlyWidget.js"...
2019-03-19T11:03:16.842Z  Creating lambda for page: "components/contactcard/components/contactform/ContactForm.js"...
2019-03-19T11:03:16.843Z  Creating lambda for page: "components/contactcard/ContactCard.js"...
2019-03-19T11:03:16.843Z  Creating lambda for page: "components/landingcard/LandingCard.js"...
2019-03-19T11:03:16.844Z  Creating lambda for page: "components/mapview/components/mapview/MapView.js"...
2019-03-19T11:03:16.844Z  Creating lambda for page: "components/mapview/MapContainer.js"...
2019-03-19T11:03:16.845Z  Creating lambda for page: "components/navbar/components/burgermenu/BurgerMenu.js"...
2019-03-19T11:03:16.845Z  Creating lambda for page: "components/navbar/NavBar.js"...
2019-03-19T11:03:16.845Z  Creating lambda for page: "components/servicescard/ServicesCard.js"...
2019-03-19T11:03:16.846Z  Creating lambda for page: "index.js"...
2019-03-19T11:03:17.851Z  Created lambda for page: "components/about/About.js"
2019-03-19T11:03:18.495Z  Created lambda for page: "components/backtotopbutton/BackToTopButton.js"
2019-03-19T11:03:19.099Z  Created lambda for page: "components/bookingcard/BookingCard.js"
2019-03-19T11:03:19.668Z  Created lambda for page: "components/bookingcard/components/calendlywidget/CalendlyWidget.js"
2019-03-19T11:03:20.169Z  Created lambda for page: "components/contactcard/components/contactform/ContactForm.js"
2019-03-19T11:03:20.923Z  Created lambda for page: "components/contactcard/ContactCard.js"
2019-03-19T11:03:21.383Z  Created lambda for page: "components/landingcard/LandingCard.js"
2019-03-19T11:03:22.061Z  Created lambda for page: "components/mapview/components/mapview/MapView.js"
2019-03-19T11:03:22.759Z  Created lambda for page: "components/mapview/MapContainer.js"
2019-03-19T11:03:23.336Z  Created lambda for page: "components/navbar/components/burgermenu/BurgerMenu.js"
2019-03-19T11:03:23.772Z  Created lambda for page: "components/navbar/NavBar.js"
2019-03-19T11:03:24.416Z  Created lambda for page: "components/servicescard/ServicesCard.js"
2019-03-19T11:03:24.988Z  Created lambda for page: "index.js"
2019-03-19T11:03:28.817Z  preparing cache ...
2019-03-19T23:29:10.708Z  REPORT RequestId: 2b7c115d-9d46-4eef-a2d9-4788ed22116a        Duration: 130.73 ms     Billed Duration: 200 ms         Memory Size: 3008 MB    Max Memory Used: 89 MB
```

Comment: check `https://zeit.co/username/websitename(package.json name)/deployment/******/logs`. post the link here

Comment: I would like to know witch version of Next.js you are using and I would like to see your next.config.js file

Comment: Since I posted I kept working on this and have changed both the now.json and next.config.js file - question is updated including logs.

Site is deployed but now the 502 error is in network request for contact form.

To aid you I have made the github repo public for this project - https://github.com/washboardalex/ctdc

Comment: Also using Now 2.0,  CLI v14.1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to use lambdas with the following `now.json`

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        { "src": "package.json", "use": "@now/next" },
        { "src": "lambda_file.js", "use": "@now/node"}
    ],
    "routes": [
        { "src": "api_route", "dest": "lambda_file.js"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: @washboardalex for more info check the PR in github

Comment: Saved me so much time, appreciate it. I'm guessing I can learn the correct routing for myself from the docs?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. But I'm not quite sure what a lambda_file.js is, can you be more specific, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a [`@now/node-server`](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/deployments/official-builders/node-js-server-now-node-server/) or [`@now/node builder`](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/deployments/official-builders/node-js-now-node/) inside now.json

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [{ "src": "package.json", "use": "@now/node-server" }]
}
```

as [`@now/next` is used for Next.js apps](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/deployments/official-builders/next-js-now-next/)

Hope this helps!